# Laravel + jquery dialog redirect after post (+fullcalendar)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a jquery dialog that has its' events dynamically altered when clicking on a single event in a fullcalendar instance like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //calendar options here              
                    events: 'getlogs',                        
                    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        //POPUPCODE START
                        $.ajax({
                           url: 'getlog',
                           data: { id: calEvent.id},
                           dataType: "json",
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               //set your values in the edit fields here
                           }
                       });
                        $('#logid').val(calEvent.id);                       
                        $("#editdeletediv").load().dialog(
                        {   //Set options for the dialog here
                                title: 'Edit/Delete log',
                                modal: true,
                                autoResize:true,
                                maxWidth: 600,
                                minWidth: 500,
                                buttons: {
                                    Delete: function(){
                                        $.ajax({
                                        url: 'removelog',
                                        type: "POST",
                                        data: { id: calEvent.id },
                                        dataType: "json"                           
                                        });                                        
                                    },
                                    Save: function(){
                                    }
                                }
                        });

                        //POPUPCODE END

                    }
            });
```

Then I have a route in my laravel routes.php that routes the post I do with the delete button to the correct controller like so:

```
Route::post('removelog/','CalendarController@removeLog');
```

The function in the controller is like this:

```
public function removeLog(){            
            $id = Input::get('id');
            DB::table('time_logs')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
        }
```

Now, this all works perfectly, there is however one downside. When I click the delete button on the dialog, it doesn't close the dialog (I know how to do this no worries) but when I do add the functionality to close the dialog it will still show the event I previously deleted. Therefore I want to refresh my page (because when I do that the event is gone seeing as they are rendered from my "getlogs" and read straight from the database) so it will no longer show the event that has already been deleted, I tried a couple of things to get this to work:

In the jquery dialog function for the delete button I added

```
 window.location.reload and later location.reload
```

This does reload my page however, it somehow breaks off my post to the remove function.

In my controller I added:

```
return Redirect::route('calendar');
```

to return to the calendar page, this didn't redirect me but the post still works so at least it didn't break anything

I also tried:

```
return Redirect::back();
```

seeing as this worked for my other post where I create a log (difference here was that that post was created using a form submit), this didn't work either

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas of how I can make this happen with the current setup I have without changing too much of the code (it's taken me ages to get everything to work and document how I did it and I wouldn't want to rewrite any of that)

Comment: Create a Success: function on the Delete button and place the location.reload in there, My first thought is that its becouse the ajax request isent processed in time and the page reloads before the ajax request is finished. Also, you should use DELETE instead of POST in the header for the deletion

Comment: You may want to try `location.href` instead of `location.reload()`.

Comment: I tried success: function(){location.href('calendar')} but that gave me an internal server error saying calendar does not exist even though it is configured in my routes.php

Comment: I get the same issue if I use location.reload()

Comment: @JeremyC.
In your PHP (after the deletion):
return Response::make(URL::route('calendar'), 204);

Then in your success function in the javascript you will get the url in your callback Success:function(result){ console.log(result); };

Im not sure whats in the result will contain but the url should be in that object. something like result.data You will see it in the log anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey so first of try using DELETE for delete requests, but that doesnt matter for functionallity.

In your Controller:

```
public function removeLog(){            
    $id = Input::get('id');
    DB::table('time_logs')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();

    return Response::json(URL::route('calendar'), 200);
}
```

In your Jquery

```
$("#editdeletediv").load().dialog(
{   //Set options for the dialog here
        title: 'Edit/Delete log',
        modal: true,
        autoResize:true,
        maxWidth: 600,
        minWidth: 500,
        buttons: {
            Delete: function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: 'removelog',
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: calEvent.id },
                dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response){
                        location.href = response;
                    }
                });                                        
            },
            Save: function(){
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: this gives me : "[2015-05-19 09:24:49] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Route [calendar] not defined.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:273" even though i have an entry in my routes.php like this : "route::get('calendar', 'CalendarController@index');"

Comment: Ah right.. you have to name your route.

Route::post('calendar', ['as'=>'calendar', 'uses'=>'CalendarController@removeLog']);

Comment: my post isn't called calendar that is my get, my post works, it's the get that doesn't when I call it from redirect, it works fine if i go through the normal paths by redirecting from menu or after form submit, just not after ajax

Comment: I did all that, the only difference is now I don't get an internal server error (just response 200 now) but I still don't get redirected, the things in the success function aren't being executed (i just tried alerting the response)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Try using window.location.href = response; instead of location.href

Comment: window.location.href = response; should work for all browsers. If its still not working, its some other issue with the code, what error do you get after the ajax requset?

Comment: yeah whatever is in the success: function(){} isn't being executed

Comment: Try using Response::json(URL::route('calendar'), 200);
It might be that jquery is trying to parse the response to json but dont recieve json. 

Also add a error: function(){} on the function to grab any errors spitted out my the ajax request

Comment: It was the json :D thanks man it works now, add that to your answer and I'll accept it